# What do the different colored flags mean?

Tags: super-mario-3d-world

In *Super Mario 3D World*, I've noticed that my levels will show various flags upon completion of a level.

What confuses me, though, is that some levels have a Gold flag, while others seem to only have a Red flag.

**What do these different colors mean?**

Comment: Additional flag information in comments below...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The different colors are showing how "good" you finished the level.

- You get a golden flag if you jump to the very top of the flagpole at the end of the level
- Green star above the flag means that you have all green stars collected in that level (3 stars every level)
- Red flag means Mario was first to the pole, pink mean Princess Peach got there first, green is Luigi, blue is Toad and light blue for Rosalina
- The green star above the flag will turn golden if you finish the level with all five playable characters.

Comment: Ooh, so the red flag means I didn't get the very top of the flag pole?

Comment: yep, but i don't know what else a red flag means, i will ask my friend

Comment: @RayofCommand - Red flag means Mario was first to the pole, pink mean Princess Peach got there first, green is Luigi, blue is Toad and light blue for Rosalina.

Comment: Also note that, after most of the postgame, the green stars will turn gold if you've completed the level with all the characters.